# How can the Lodash orderBy function be made to work with accented characters?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way to make Lodash's orderBy function support accented characters?

Like á, é, ñ, etc. These are moved to the end of the array when the sort is performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by comparing a sanitized element.

```
theArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().removeAccents().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase().removeAccents());
});
```

The removeAccents function:

```
String.prototype.removeAccents = function () {
return this
    .replace(/[áàãâä]/gi,"a")
    .replace(/[éè¨ê]/gi,"e")
    .replace(/[íìïî]/gi,"i")
    .replace(/[óòöôõ]/gi,"o")
    .replace(/[úùüû]/gi, "u")
    .replace(/[ç]/gi, "c")
    .replace(/[ñ]/gi, "n")
    .replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g," ");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, unfortunately.

Answer (score 12):

#### The Problem

It sounds like it doesn't use `localeCompare`, defaulting instead to the equivalent of using `<` or `>`, which compares by UTF-16 code unit numeric values, not locale-aware collation (ordering).

#### Controlling Comparison Method

You can convert to array (if needed) and then use the native `sort` with [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). For instance, instead of:

```js
const result = _.orderBy(theArray, ["value"]);
```

you can do:

```js
const result = theArray.slice().sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));
```

or to sort in-place:

```js
theArray.sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));
```

`localeCompare` uses the default collation order for the default locale. Using [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator), you can have more control over the collation (like case-insensitivity, the handling of accents, the relative position of upper- and lower-case characters, etc.). For instance, if you wanted the default collation for the default locale but with upper-case characters first:

```js
const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {caseFirst: "upper"});
const result = theArray.slice().sort((a, b) => collator.compare(a.value, b.value));
```

Live Example:

```js
const theArray = [
    {value: "n"},
    {value: "N"},
    {value: "ñ"},
    {value: "á"},
    {value: "A"},
    {value: "a"},
];
const lodashResult = _.orderBy(theArray, ["value"]);
const localeCompareResult = theArray.slice().sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value));
const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {caseFirst: "upper"});
const collatorResult = theArray.slice().sort((a, b) => collator.compare(a.value, b.value));
show("unsorted:", theArray);
show("lodashResult:", lodashResult);
show("localeCompareResult:", localeCompareResult);
show("collatorResult:", collatorResult);

function show(label, array) {
    console.log(label, "[");
    for (const element of array) {
        console.log(`    ${JSON.stringify(element)}`);
    }
    console.log("]");
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

#### Stable vs Unstable Sort

When I first wrote this answer, there was a slight difference between `_.orderBy` and the native `sort`: `_.orderBy`, like [`_.sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy), always does a *stable sort*, whereas at the time of the original answer JavaScript's native `sort` was not guaranteed to be stable. Since then, though, the [JavaScript specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) has been modified to require a stable sort (ES2019). So both `_.orderBy`/`_.sortBy` and native `sort` are stable now.

If "stable" vs. "unstable" sort aren't familiar terms: A "stable" sort is one where two elements that are considered equivalent for sorting purposes are guaranteed to remain in the same position relative to each other; in an "unstable" sort, their positions relative to to each other might be swapped (which is allowed because they're "equivalent" for sorting purposes). Consider this array:

```js
const theArray = [
    {value: "x", id: 27},
    {value: "z", id: 14},
    {value: "x", id: 12},
];
```

If you do an *unstable* sort that sorts ascending on just `value` (disregarding `id` or any other properties the objects might have), there are two valid results:

```js
// Valid result 1: id = 27 remained in front of id = 12
[
    {value: "x", id: 27},
    {value: "x", id: 12},
    {value: "z", id: 14},
]
// Valid result 2: id = 27 was moved after id = 12
[
    {value: "x", id: 12},
    {value: "x", id: 27},
    {value: "z", id: 14},
]
```

With a stable sort, though, only the first result is valid; the positions of equivalent elements relative to each other remains unchanged.

But again, that distinction no longer matters, since JavaScript's `sort` is stable now too.

Comment: Just keep in mind though that this will not be a stable sort, and will be subject to the algorithm that browser picks up for .sort internally (depending for example on the length of array).

Comment: @user776686 what do you mean exactly? can you give some more detailed explanation? like a page (URL) where to read more?

Comment: @stackoverflow - The comment was referring to the fact that Lodash's `_.orderBy`/`_.sortBy` guaranteed a stable sort, while JavaScript's `sort` didn't (it was allowed to be unstable). But ES2019 changed the JavaScript spec to require a stable sort, so that's no longer relevant. (All major JavaScript engines already implemented a stable sort IIRC, so the spec change didn't actually change what they did, just documented it and required it of other less-prevalent implementations.) I've updated the answer to explain that and to briefly explain stable vs. unstable sorting.

Comment: nice job @T.J.Crowder thanks for the info